# Battery-less Self-charging Graphics Tablet Pens - EMI

Tags: induction

This is a hardware related question. A lot of the new graphics tablets have self-charging, battery-less pens. I assume the charging is inductive, either off the screen surface or from an antenna within the tablet.

Can anyone please tell me more precisely how this works, at what approximate frequency, and if it represents a source of possible interference to other electronic devices in close proximity?

Comment: Which particular pens?

Comment: perhaps you should be asking the manufacturer